# mysql error update or insert failing

Tags: mysql, insert, unique

I'm going blind here... can't seem to find the error in this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO sankt_groups_order (
    parent_group_id, 
    child_group_id, 
    order
) VALUES (?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    order = ?
;
```

I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
    1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
    near 'order ) VALUES ('65',NULL,'3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE order = '3''
```

Next will this SQL do what I think? I need it to insert the whole row if missing and update order if it exists... I have an index making `parent_group_id` and `child_group_id` unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql, you'll have to escape it:

```
    child_group_id, 
    `order`
    ^--   ^--- backticks to escape
) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

and yes, it should do what you think. If there's a unique/primary key violation, you'll only change the `order` field.

Comment: Yes. Thank you that seemed to do the trick :) Forgot about those damn reserved words... I would have wished for a better error message though :)

Comment: unfortunately, that's why they're reserved. mysql only sees what you wrote, and sees "order", thinking "hmm, looks like the coder's jumped from field lists to an order clause without a from/where"